# Hiding a deprecated sharepoint web

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to hide a Sharepoint web that has been deprecated (via custom means) due to the release of a newer version, whether it would be making it invisible in the sites and workspaces, or via some special archiving function provided by Sharepoint.  Basically I do not wish the users to be able to see the deprecated site.

I was wondering what are the options for doing so, both programmatically or via Sharepoint utils/interfaces?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

The scenario where I want to hide the web from the users (e.g. Webv1.0 when Web2.0 is available) is a bit like, okay, I have version 2.0 of Software X downloaded and installed, and it has converted all of my data into version 2.0 format so it will be compatible with new features.  As a user, I would not want to use Software X version 1.0 anymore since it is now old.  Of course I would want a backup copy of my data from version 1.0, but I probably don't want to be confused by having a link here which can get me to version 1.0 of the software (and from a developer's point of view, it'll be extra unnecessary work to make version 1.0 being viewable/editable in version 2.0).

I thought of the idea of using security to only allow admins to see everything, but I want to explore other options first e.g. whether it is possible to make the link to the old site disappear programmatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you only want to hide it or should it be unaccessible for the users?

Comment: @Flo: a bit of both really.  Users surely shouldn't be able to see something that has been deprecated, but I'm not sure whether Sharepoint can hide a web, though.  I know if I want it to be inaccessible to the users I can try with the permissions, but I'll leave that as a last resort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you just remove all access to that site (by breaking security inheritance) and just allow admins only access to it?

Answer (score 1):

Colin's answer sounds like the way to go. Alternatively you can inject a little bit of JavaScript that automatically redirects the user to the new version of the site.

You can add JavaScript using a content Editor Web Part (one page at a time) or by using the free [SharePoint Infuser](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Infuser-(Free).aspx) (all pages in one go).

Comment: +1 I like this idea - just locking down the security lets users know the site still exists but they have been denied access it, which could be confusing and add to helpdesk queries. You could have the CEWP show a big red message "this site has been deprecated: users can't see it" for administrators or otherwise inject the redirect script. Then you just need to add that webpart to any deprecated sites in future. Don't forget to exclude the site from the search content sources as well so it doesn't appear in search results

Comment: I do not want the users to be able to see the deprecated web at all.  I have updated my post with a bit more information.

Comment: Muhimbi's answer will redirect users to the appropriate site even if they have kept direct links to it. The issue with locking the site down using security is that users with direct links to the site will still go there but get an "access denied" message rather than automatically being redirected to the most up to date site. This will lead to support issues. Redirection seems to me to be a frictionless solution.